# Optimisation question: using a dictionary from file 1 to convert a file 2

Tags: python, bash, optimization, awk

I am trying to transform a file 1 (a gtf file if any bioinformatician pass by) with lines like:

```
1   X   exon    1   300000  1000    -   .   gene_id "Z.633"; transcript_id "Z.633.mrna1"; exon_number "1"; 
1   X   transcript  1   300000  1000    -   .   gene_id "Z.633"; transcript_id "Z.633.mrna1"; 
1   X   exon    300005  300500  1000    -   .   gene_id "Y.6330"; transcript_id "Y.6330.mrna1"; exon_number "2";
1   X   exon    300500  310000  1000    +   .   gene_id "Y.6330"; transcript_id "Y.6330.mrna1"; exon_number "1"; 
1   X   transcript  30005   310000  1000    +   .   gene_id "Y.6330"; transcript_id "Y.6330.mrna1";
```

into a file in which all "Z" will be replaced by "F", and other correspondances. All correspondances are in a file 2 that I use as a dictionary, column 1 being keys, column 2 being values.

example file 2:

```
Z.633 F.633
Y.6330 U.6330
```

example result :

```
1   X   exon    1   300000  1000    -   .   gene_id "F.633"; transcript_id "F.633.mrna1"; exon_number "1"; 
1   X   transcript  1   300000  1000    -   .   gene_id "F.633"; transcript_id "F.633.mrna1"; 
1   X   exon    300005  300500  1000    -   .   gene_id "U.6330"; transcript_id "U.6330.mrna1"; exon_number "2";
1   X   exon    300500  310000  1000    +   .   gene_id "U.6330"; transcript_id "U.6330.mrna1"; exon_number "1"; 
1   X   transcript  30005   310000  1000    +   .   gene_id "U.6330"; transcript_id "U.6330.mrna1";
```

file1 has circa 200000 lines and file2 has 20000.

To do that, I used an awk script:

```
NR == FNR {
  rep[ $2 ] = $1 
  next
} 

{
  for (key in rep)
    gsub(key, rep[key])
  print
}
```

and then:

```sh
awk -f dict.awk file2 file1 > newfile
```

My problem is that the script actually runs for days... Is there any way I could improve that?
Is there a more appropriated programming language for this problem? (I tried python but the running time was even worse)

(script python used:)

```
def replaceWithDictionnary(dictFileName,fileToReplaceName,newFileName):
    import re
    with open(dictFileName,'r') as d:
        dictFile = dict((line.strip().split())[::-1] for line in d)
        
    with open(newFileName,'w') as g:
        with open(fileToReplaceName,'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                for d_key, d_value in dictFile.items():
                    if bool(re.search(d_key+"\D+", line)):
                    #if "\""+d_key+"\"" in line:
                        #print(d_key)
                        newline=line.replace(d_key,d_value)
                        #print(d_value)
                        g.write(newline)
                        continue
```

I can tell it's not the dictionary part that takes so long because I tested it with a smaller file1 and it ran quickly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one `gene_id` to be replaced per record, which can always be found at the 10th column, like in your sample file, you can locate it and call `gsub` once, instead of calling 20K functions per record.

```
> cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
  r[$1] = $2
  next
}

{
  x = $10
  gsub(/"|;/, "", x)   
  gsub(x, r[x])
  print
}
```

---

```
awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
```